# Are there any coding standards for VBA within Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, error-code

Especially, I'd like to know when it is appropriate to output one or other of the standard error codes (viz#N/A, #REF!, #NAME?, #DIV/0!, #NULL!, #VALUE! and #NUM!) in response to bad inputs.

For example, which one is the best to be output in the event that a negative value is given as the second parameter to a Beta function?

Comment: There are some nice recommendations here: http://www.eusprig.org/best-practice.htm  I specially liked the doc called "How do you know your spreadsheet is right ?"

Comment: MS has this, which is similar to the answer from @barrowc but more detailed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687844.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#NUM!` would be the appropriate error.

From Excel's help:

`#NUM!` Occurs with invalid numeric values in a formula or function.

For completeness, the descriptions of the other errors are as follows:

`#####` Occurs when a column is not wide enough, or a negative date or time is used.

`#VALUE!` Occurs when the wrong type of argument or operand is used.

`#DIV/0!` Occurs when a number is divided by zero (0).

`#NAME?` Occurs when Microsoft Excel doesn't recognize text in a formula.

`#N/A` Occurs when a value is not available to a function or formula.

`#REF!` Occurs when a cell reference is not valid.

`#NULL!` Occurs when you specify an intersection of two areas that do not intersect. The intersection operator is a space between references.